# Can we navigate inside one component to another in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a application with navigation bar with links to course and assignment component. When we click on course, course component is getting loaded. Now I want to achieve a functionality where I click on one course respective assignment should be displayed. Assignment component is already present.

Answer (score 1):

As per the information present here. A small model popup can be added on Course component click and on the click of that course component the popup will show all the assignments corresponding to that course. One have to create link to all the assignment components and keep a relationship between the assignment components and the course components in the links and load only those assignment component links in the model popup whichever course is clicked.